# Binding Comboboxes inside an Itemscontrol

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am having trouble with a combination of `ComboBox'es` inside an `ItemsControl`.
What I am trying to do is create a List of `ComboBox'es`. At the start there is only one default `ComboBox` with a default value. If you select any other type than the default type, a new `ComboBox` is added with the default type in it.
Now, each Item in the `List` actually contains of 2 `Combobox'es`. The second box displays the number, this type is present.

**Before:**
[image: Before]

**After:**
[image: After]

Now I want to update the numbers in the second box if any other number in the `ItemsControl` changes. How do I do that?

Here is the relevant code:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ChosenAppartmentTypeList}" Margin="10">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox Margin="10" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:GeneralProjectDataView}}, Path=DataContext.AppartmentTypeList}">
               <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                  <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                     <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:GeneralProjectDataView}},                               Path=DataContext.ComboBoxSelectedItemChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox},                                                         Path=SelectedItem}" />
                     </i:EventTrigger>
                  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                     </DataTemplate>
                   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
             </ComboBox>
             <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:GeneralProjectDataView}},   Path=DataContext.NumberList}" SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Path=SelectedItem.Count}" SelectedIndex="0">
                <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ComboBox>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Those are the lists:

```
    public ObservableCollection<AppartmentType> AppartmentTypeList { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<AppartmentType> ChosenAppartmentTypeList { get; set; }
```

And those are the properties:

```
public class AppartmentType : ValidatableBindableBase
{
    private string name;
    private int count;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref name, value); }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set { SetProperty(ref count, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can observe your property ChosenAppartmentTypeList via PropertyChanged event and update the ApartmentType items. 
[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668610%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Secondly, your SelectedItem on second combobox must be bound two-way.